# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception in react native app

Tags: react-native

I have created my first project and try to run on my android device but it was an error like this.

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

*** What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> The SDK directory '/home/ford/Android/sdk' does not exist.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to the android/ directory of your react-native project
- Create a file called local.properties with this line:
  sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk or the android sdk directory where it is installed
- Where USERNAME is your OSX username